# Creating an OnLoad Function

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce

I have a code that inserts custom content into tinyMCE. I have used this code as a click function and it worked, so I was wondering how I could make it into something that happens on body load.

Here is the raw code:

```
tinyMCE.get('elm1').execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<? echo $videocode; ?>');return false;
```

And here is what I've tried in an onLoad:

```
<body onload="tinyMCE.get('elm1').execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<? echo $videocode; ?>');return false;">
```

Currently, the return false part shows up as raw HTML on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use `document.onload` instead of `<body onload="">`.

```
document.onload = function(){
    tinyMCE.get('elm1').execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<?=$videocode;?>');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I am noting this!  I appreciate the advice.  Let me try it out